# Assigning multiple materials to a gameobject through script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I assign multiple materials to a gameobject through c# script?

What I have tried so far is:

```
public GameObject go;
public Material Mat1;
public Material Mat2;
void Start()
{ 
     //this does not work
     go.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0] = Mat1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the materials directly, but you need to create a new materials array and assign it.

```
void Start()
    {
        //create your materials
        var yourMaterials = new Material[] { Mat1, Mat2 };
        //assign it
        go.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = yourMaterials ;
    }
```

You may also check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html).

> Note that like all arrays returned by Unity, this returns a copy of
>   materials array. If you want to change some materials in it, get the
>   value, change an entry and set materials back.

Comment: Also on [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1312459/unable-to-set-second-material-programmatically.html), just in case 3 answers of the same type in 6 minutes were not enough :).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Note that like all arrays returned by Unity, this returns a copy of materials array. If you want to change some materials in it, get the value, change an entry and set materials back.

```
Renderer rend = go.GetComponent<Renderer>();
Material [] mats = rend.materials;
mats[0] = Mat1;
rend.materials = mats;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change multiple materials you need to change the whole array.
so you first create an array of materials with the same length as the current renderer:

```
Material[] newMaterials = renderer.sharedMaterials;
for(int i = 0; i <newMaterials.Length; i++)
{
newMaterials[i] = theMaterialYouWantToSetX;
}
```

and then you assign the array to the renderer:

```
renderer.materials = newMaterials;
```